# Bibtex Error 2D and 3D

Tags: biblatex

I have found an error in Bibtex file, i.e.

in bib file

```
@article{Hello,
title = "2D and 3D implementation of a method
...
}
```

the resulting Pdf is **2d** and **3d** implementation of a method

why we cannot get "2D, 3D" in PDF?

Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding braces to keep capitalization:

```
@article{Hello,
title = "{2D} and {3D} implementation of a method",
}
```

Comment: Please don't add braces around the entire title as in `title = "{2D and 3D implementation of a method}",` or `title = {{2D and 3D implementation of a method}},`. Instead use Title Case and protect only those words that need protection: `title = {{2D} and {3D} Implementation of a Method},`.

Comment: @moewe Fixed, thanks for your valuable advice!